# unable to understand Null pointer in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am working on singly linked list and unable to solve problem (I think the problem is in add function something with NULL pointer), the problem is it only adding first number to list and skipping rest of call to add function.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct node
{
  int i;
  struct node* next;
};

struct node* head = NULL;

int add(int val)
{
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->i = val;
  }
  else
  {
    struct node* current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->i = val;
  }
}

int print(struct node* first)
{
  while(first != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\n",first->i);
    first = first->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  add(36);
  add(46);
  add(97);
  print(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @underscore_d That's called C++, and it's irrelevant here, if you want to try to stop people asking about linked lists take it up on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here.  First, when creating a new node you don't set `next` to NULL.  So when you iterate through the list, you end up reading garbage data, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then next problem is that when you iterate through a non-empty list, you "fall off" the end of the list, so `current` is NULL at the end of the loop and there's no link to the end of the list.  You need to stop when `current->next` is null, then create the new node there.

```
void add(int val)     // change return type to void since nothing is being returned
{
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  // don't cast return value of malloc
    head->i = val;
    head->next = NULL;                   // terminate list
  }
  else
  {
    struct node* current = head;
    while(current->next != NULL)         // loop until you're on the last node
    {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->next->i = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;          // terminate list
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought an uninitialized pointer is same as NULL pointer in c,  this helped me clear my doubt.

Comment: @neeraj_nigam There is also an option to zero initialize each node with `calloc`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) for more information. The calling syntax is a little different, but not too crazy.

Answer (score 2):

You are never setting `node->next` to `NULL` (for both `head->next` and `current->next` paths). Allocating using `malloc` does not clear the allocated memory, so you need to do this yourself.

Also, when you are adding the second element, you are iterating until `current` reaches `NULL`, but you never set `previous_node->next` to point to new element, so you never actually "link" anything in your linked list.

Also, you [shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565496/1488067).

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why you do not see the effects of adding the second and subsequent nodes is that when you allocate a new node that is not the head node, you store the pointer to it only in local variable `current` of function `add()`.  You need to instead store it in the `next` pointer of the previous node.  Compare this with your original code:

```
    struct node* current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(*current->next));
```

Note also that, as @Lousy observed also, you fail to set the `next` pointers of new nodes to `NULL`.  You must do this, for until you assign some value to those fields, their contents are indeterminate.